# Wordpress pagination give duplicate content

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, permalinks, custom-wordpress-pages

So i change my wordpress permalink with custom structure "/%category%/%postname%/".
However, if i type manually "/poem/page/2", then it works. But the content of every page is the same. Wether it was "/page/3" or "/page/4", it was all the same.

at first, when i access "/page/2/", my page was giving "404 error". But i got this code from the internet, and when i use the code, it started to work. But, the content of every page is the same. The code goes on like this :

on function.php:

````
function vipx_filter_category_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    $categories = get_categories( array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );

    if ( is_array( $categories ) && ! empty( $categories ) ) {
        $slugs = array();
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
            if ( is_object( $category ) && ! is_wp_error( $category ) ) {
                if ( 0 == $category->category_parent ) {
                    $slugs[] = $category->slug;
                } else {
                    $slugs[] = trim( get_category_parents( $category->term_id, false, '/', true ), '/' );
                }
            }
        }

        if ( ! empty( $slugs ) ) {
            $rules = array();

            foreach ( $slugs as $slug ) {
                $rules[ '(' . $slug . ')/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)?/?$' ] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
                $rules[ '(' . $slug . ')/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' ] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
                $rules[ '(' . $slug . ')(/page/(\d)+/?)?$' ] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[3]';
            }
        }
    }
    return $rules;
}```

this is my loop post :
````

```
?php 
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            echo $paged;
            $term = get_queried_object();
            $data = array( 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'category_name' => $term->slug, 'page'=>$paged );

            $get_category_post = new WP_Query( $data );

        ?>
        <?php if ( $get_category_post->have_posts() ) : while ( $get_category_post->have_posts() ) : $get_category_post->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post__list">
            <?php if($term->slug === 'analect' || $term->slug === 'collection') { ?>
            <span>for other categories</span>
        <?php } else {?>
        <span> <?php the_content(); ?> </span>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php 
            next_posts_link(); 
            previous_posts_link();  
        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: try to change the 'page' to 'paged' inside your $data

Comment: bless you sir. It works ! i feel so stupid for spending 5 hours on this